# Fortran matrix with different data types or mixed precision according to different columns (or rows)

Tags: arrays, pointers, matrix, fortran, mixed

In short, what I want is:

**custom_2d_matrix(n, m) where 1..x are arrays of integers with size n and x+1..m are arrays of real numbers with size m. (1 <= x <= m)**

---

For example, I want to create a custom type, which is a mixed precision matrix, or you can call it a matrix with different data types.

1. The custom_2d_matrix has *n* rows and *m* columns.
2. Column number from 1 to *x* are column vectors with integer data type.
3. Column number from *x* to *m* are column vectors with real data type.
4. Note that 1 <= *x* <= *m*
5. The custom_2d_matrix must be accessible through index only. For example, custom_2d_matrix(i, j) will bring up the i-th array (can be either integer array or real array) and then the j-th element in the said array. So for this reason, derived type is not good enough.

Comment: @francescalus I have shortened the description and the title and hopefully it is much clearer now.

Comment: Does a derived type work for you? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? It sounds like an xy problem to me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If I already know the first x-th columns are the integer rows and the rest are the real columns, then I know the types of the pointers. However, the array of pointers itself must be mixed type, which is impossible... Using derived type makes it no longer a matrix.

Comment: @Ross Derived type is not good enough because it is not accessible only by index, see 5. I have removed the "array of pointers" sentence so that it is no longer a XY problem.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I thought so. Not able to set the values using the proposed method is indeed undesirable. Thank you for helping anyway!

Comment: It's (most probably) still a xy problem. You seem to be trying to solve another problem (unknown  to us), whose solution you assumed is making this strange data-type; thus, you ask how to do this data-type. Instead, tell us what is the previous, original, true problem, and maybe we can advise you to another, more suitable solution.

Comment: About the approach you presented in the question, long story short: Fortran is stacticly-typed. You **must** know, at the point you are calling a function, accessing a type-component or doing an operation, what type is the result if you want to store it into a variable or pass it away as an argument (i.e. any useful work). You *might* code a data-type or function that returns a "real or a integer", but you'd need to know beforehand which type it would be in order to use it. If you need more explanation on this, we could write a proper answer, but would be better to solve your original issue.